# matlab error while plotting graph

Tags: matlab

I have written a code to implement differentiator and integrator using matlab.I'm able to get the outputs of the differentiation and integration but i have trouble while plotting the graph.I get the error as below.

> conversion from double to sym is not possible .

I have attached the code below .

```
clc;
close all;
syms t;
y=input('Enter the function : ');
T=input('enter the period of the function : ');
t=0:0.001*(1/T):1/T;
intop=int(y)
difop=diff(y)
figure(1)
plot(t,intop);
xlabel('time in t');
ylabel('Amplitude ');
title('integrator o/p');
zoom;
grid;
figure(2)
plot(t,difop);
xlabel('time in t');
ylabel('Amplitude ');
title('diffrentiator  o/p');
zoom;
grid;
```

Please let me know where i'm going wrong.

Comment: why a down vote ?. i have done googling before asking here. i have tried using subs but haven't succeeded with the same .If you know the solution please let me know.

Comment: why do you declare `t` as a `syms` in line `3`, yet assign it a range of floats in line `6`?

Comment: @Schorsch thanks for noting the same , read about symbolic variables bit thoroughly and could plot the graph using ezplot.The issue can now be closed.

Comment: The down vote is because the question does not show any research effort. You say that have googled it, and tried to use subs, but it is not mentioned in your question.
I'm sorry but it really sounded as "I have no intention to put any effort on this". If you edit the question to include the final solution (and other details you consider worthy) in the main text, i'll be glad to remove the downvote :-)

Comment: @dunadar : The issue is resolved and here is the working code http://pastebin.com/LTLf9u64.